# SSRS : User should have flexibility to select one or more records and Export those records to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

My client wants the flexibility to select one or more records from the final data within the report displayed in the Report Manager. Can anyone please provide a solution?

Detail Info: The current report has 4 parameters(mainly drop down lists/Multi select option)) for the user to select. Once the user selects the options and clicks "View Report", the filtered data is displayed which can be hundreds of rows of data. 
But the user only needs some records and not all records. Hence the users wants the flexibility of selecting one or more records from the above mentioned rows of data. The selected records needs to be then exported to Excel.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

One record? Easy - just use the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207116.aspx) properties of the cell's text box to open the Excel version of the report for just that one record.

More records? Not so much. SSRS is a reporting tool, not a user interface for data management.